# Max value for each key in a list

Tags: python

Given:

```
scooby = [1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4]
snacks = [6,28,14, 3, 9, 8,18, 6, 7]
scoobysnacks = zip(scooby,snacks)
```

How do I run `max(scoobysnacks)` to get:

```
(1,18)
(4,28)
```

The logic being that *18* is the max value associated to a *1* and *28* the max value associated to a *4*.

Comment: What is the logic behind the output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples - it will give you an idea of the tools Python has to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't, because that's not what `max` does.

Comment: Oh I get it! Here is what you want: `scoobysnacks = list(zip(scooby, snacks)); print([(x, max(j for i, j in scoobysnacks if i == x)) for x in set(scooby)]);`

Comment: Use pandas, `import pandas as pd`  `pd.DataFrame({'scooby':scooby,'snacks':snacks}).groupby('scooby',as_index=False)['snacks'].max().apply(tuple, 1).tolist()`

Comment: Yes, thanks for trying to understand me being obtuse... if scooby were a list of ids and snacks were values, I'm trying to do the equivalent of a T-SQL:SELECT scooby, Max([snacks])
  FROM [data table]
  group by scooby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that traverses the lists only once, keeping track of the best pairs with a `dict`.

```
scooby = [1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4]
snacks = [6,28,14, 3, 9, 8,18, 6, 7]

pairs= {}
for x, y in zip(scooby, snacks):
    pairs[x] = max(pairs.get(x, y), y)

output = list(pairs.items())

output  # [(1, 18), (4, 28)]
```

Comment: I had no idea you could enumerate and embed an "if" in the max function... fantastic!  Where do I learn more?  Also, how would the function change if the lists were ordered by scooby? scooby = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]
snacks = [6, 14, 9, 18, 6, 28,3, 8, 7]

Comment: It'd probably be simpler to use `zip(scooby, snacks)` instead of `enumerate`.

Comment: Second solution is much better. Could opt for a `defaultdict` too.

Comment: @miradulo that would be the case only if we know the values are positive

Comment: @OlivierMelançon True, an assumption on my part :) depends if you motivated the default factory further or not too.

Answer (score 1):

```
list(dict(sorted(zip(scooby, snacks))).items())

[(1, 18), (4, 28)]
```

---

### Crappy one-liner in O(n)

```
[
    (k, max(v)) for k, v in 
    (lambda d, x=defaultdict(list): ([x[k].append(v) for k, v in d], x))
    (zip(scooby, snacks))[1].items()
]
```